# Search in file explorer got stuck in Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: files, directory, search

I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.10 a few days ago from 22.04. In 22.10, I have encountered few errors. The most prominent one is error in file or directory search in the default Ubuntu Files app. Every time I started typing for files or folders, the file explorer got stuck for a long time.

[image: 1]

After a moment when I was trying to minimize the tab, I got a *"Files" is not responding* error.

[image: file not responding error]

Comment: Is your system fully updated? Nautilus in 22.10 has quite a few bugs. Some of them are being addressed and others will stay until the next release (in 23.04).

Comment: Thanks @FedKad After your comment I have updated Nautilus to 43.0. It's now working now. But in times, It got stuck as it was. After a logout-login to the system make the Nautilus works fine every time.